# Grouping Dataframe based on sequential criteria

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, data-cleaning

I have a data as follows

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 | 55 | A | - | A |
| 02/01/2024 | 56 | - | B | B |
| 03/01/2024 | 58 | A | - | A |
| 04/01/2024 | 59 | - | B | B |
| 05/01/2024 | 62 | A | - | A |
| 06/01/2024 | 63 | A | - | A |
| 07/01/2024 | 69 | - | B | B |
| 08/01/2024 | 72 | A | - | A |
| 09/01/2024 | 74 | - | B | B |
| 10/01/2024 | 78 | A | - | A |
| 11/01/2024 | 85 | - | B | B |
| 12/01/2024 | 88 | - | B | B |
| 13/01/2024 | 92 | - | B | B |

I want the output to look as follows

<Group 1>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2024 | 55 | A | - | A |

<Group 2>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/01/2024 | 56 | - | B | B |

<Group 3>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/01/2024 | 58 | A | - | A |

<Group 4>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04/01/2024 | 59 | - | B | B |

<Group 5>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/01/2024 | 62 | A | - | A |
| 06/01/2024 | 63 | A | - | A |

<Group 6>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/01/2024 | 69 | - | B | B |

<Group 7>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/01/2024 | 72 | A | - | A |

<Group 8>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/01/2024 | 74 | - | B | B |

<Group 9>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/01/2024 | 78 | A | - | A |

<Group 10>

| Date | Values | Attribute A | Attribute B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/01/2024 | 85 | - | B | B |
| 12/01/2024 | 88 | - | B | B |
| 13/01/2024 | 92 | - | B | B |

Basically I will require to create a loop to segregate the data in the above fashion and where the output will be appended as dataframes to a list.

I tried using groupby function with a lot of trial and error, however I've been only able to create 2 groups namely Group A and Group B without giving any importance to break of group.

I need to study these 10 groups independently and thereby Il require such code to clean/ arrange the data.

The real data is way long with 1000s of timeseries entries and thus a group by itself can also have 100s of items (in above example refer Group 5 and 10)

Comment: please format your question in a better way, it's not so easy to know what your desired results should look like

Comment: Already looks much better, and it seems you have a nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Create helper Series by compare shifted values with cumulative sum of column `Group` and loop:

```
for name, g in df.groupby(df['Group'].ne(df['Group'].shift()).cumsum()):
    print (f'<Group {name}>')
    print (g)
```

---

```
<Group 1>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
0  01/01/2024        55           A            -      A
<Group 2>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
1  02/01/2024        56           -            B      B
<Group 3>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
2  03/01/2024        58           A            -      A
<Group 4>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
3  04/01/2024        59           -            B      B
<Group 5>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
4  05/01/2024        62           A            -      A
5  06/01/2024        63           A            -      A
<Group 6>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
6  07/01/2024        69           -            B      B
<Group 7>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
7  08/01/2024        72           A            -      A
<Group 8>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
8  09/01/2024        74           -            B      B
<Group 9>
         Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
9  10/01/2024        78           A            -      A
<Group 10>
          Date   Values  Attribute A  Attribute B  Group
10  11/01/2024        85           -            B      B
11  12/01/2024        88           -            B      B
12  13/01/2024        92           -            B      B
```